# CAN RX interrupt freezing on STM32

Tags: stm32, can-bus, cortex-m, stm32f4, canopen

I have a problem that my RX interrupt callback doesn't trigger after some time of running state (sometimes 30 seconds, sometimes 10 minutes...), and I don't know any more where to look for the failure.

I am using a CANopen stack from Emtas, but this stack doesn't enable nor disable interrupts according to fa. Emtas, and I am also not using IT disables. The CPU doesn't freeze; it runs in the loop even after the RX freeze.

INFO: CPU-STM32f429, EMTAS CANOpen, Atollic lite, HAL libraries.

Code flow:

```
while(1){
    CanOpenTask();
    SPI1communicatin(); // Polled
    CanOpenTask();
    SPI3communicatin(); // Polled
    CanOpenTask();
    SPI6communicatin(); // Polled
}
```

CAN settings:

```
GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_8|GPIO_PIN_9;
GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF9_CAN1;
HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

/* Peripheral interrupt init */
HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(CAN1_TX_IRQn, 2, 0);
HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(CAN1_TX_IRQn);
HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(CAN1_RX0_IRQn, 1, 0);
HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(CAN1_RX0_IRQn);
HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(CAN1_SCE_IRQn, 3, 0);
HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(CAN1_SCE_IRQn);

hcan1.Instance = CAN1;
hcan1.Init.Prescaler = 6;
hcan1.Init.Mode = CAN_MODE_NORMAL;
hcan1.Init.SJW = CAN_SJW_1TQ;
hcan1.Init.BS1 = CAN_BS1_12TQ;
hcan1.Init.BS2 = CAN_BS2_2TQ;
hcan1.Init.TTCM = DISABLE;
hcan1.Init.ABOM = DISABLE;
hcan1.Init.AWUM = DISABLE;
hcan1.Init.NART = DISABLE;
hcan1.Init.RFLM = DISABLE;
hcan1.Init.TXFP = DISABLE;
if (HAL_CAN_Init(&hcan1) != HAL_OK)
{
    Error_Handler();
}
```

Where/how do I search for the reason of this problem?

Comment: Recently had a similar issue with CAN (also canopen). Works for up to an hour or so, then dies. Was using a Nucleo F4 on internal clock, switched to using an external crystal clock (25MHz) and no more errors. No Tx Rx errors at all. Previously with the internal clock (16MHz) the error counts stabilised at roughly 0x40.

Comment: What is "fa" (near "Emtas")?

Comment: fa. is Firma/Companny, english is not my native language...